# NodeJS: write http response with JavaScript content

Tags: node.js, http

I have a server running on port **5000** and users don’t have access to this port.

I started another node server on **4000** and want to read the http content (`localhost:5000/test`) (content has javascripts) and users should see it on the browser by accessing port `localhost:4000/test`

Something like http content forward not the URL forward.

Any examples? Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do this with NGINX with a config file and no programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem, I would recommend using a proxy such as https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
The code that you would need to implement on your server on port 4000 should look something like this:

```
const http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
//
// Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://localhost:5000'}).listen(4000);
```